# Need help deleting kivy widgets

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I have two main files.py and demo.kv. When executing the **add_item function**, I add 4 widgets (Label - 3 and MDRaisedButton - 1) and they form a string.

I want some way to **press the 'delete this'** button in a row to delete that particular row.
I imagine I'd need some way to differentiate between these generated rows somehow but I haven't gotten that figured out yet either. I'd be extatic if someone had an elegant solution for this, as I've been stuck here for quite some time.

**main.py**

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window

from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
from kivymd.uix.button import MDRaisedButton

Window.size = (500, 600)


finalPrice = []

finalItems = []

finalCounter = []

class MainApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = 'Blue'
        return Builder.load_file('demo.kv')


    def add_item(self, name, price, counter):


        mdRB = MDRaisedButton(text='delete this')
        mdRB.bind(on_press=self.delete_mdRB)

        self.root.ids.basketItems.add_widget(
            MDLabel(text=name, adaptive_height=True, adaptive_width=True)
        )
        self.root.ids.basketItems.add_widget(
            MDLabel(text=price, adaptive_height=True, adaptive_width=True, width=60, size_hint_x=None)
        )
        self.root.ids.basketItems.add_widget(
            MDLabel(text=counter, adaptive_height=True, adaptive_width=True, width=120, size_hint_x=None)
        )
        self.root.ids.basketItems.add_widget(
            mdRB
        )

    def delete_mdRB(self):
        for child in [child for child in self.root.ids.basketItems.children]:
            self.root.ids.basketItems.remove_widget(child)

        finalPrice.clear()
        print(finalPrice)

        finalItems.clear()
        print(finalItems)

        finalCounter.clear()
        print(finalCounter)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

**demo.kv**

```
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory

<Bases@Popup>
    auto_dismiss: True
    title: 'Item'

    background_normal: ""
    background_color: (26/255, 149/255, 184/255, .9)

    ScrollView:
        size: self.size

        GridLayout:

            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.minimum_height
            width: self.minimum_width

            cols: 3

            size: root.width * 0.5, root.height * 0.5
            row_default_height: 35
            row_force_default: True
            center: root.width / 1, root.height / 1

            Label:
                text: ''
            Label:
                text: ''
            Button:
                text: 'Close'
                font_size: 12
                on_release: root.dismiss()

            Label:
                text: 'Name'
                font_size: 12
                text_size: self.size
                halign: 'left'
                valign: 'middle'

            Label:
                text: 'Кол-во'
                font_size: 12
                text_size: self.size
                halign: 'right'
                valign: 'middle'
            Label:
                text: 'Basket'
                font_size: 12

            Label:
                text: f'Item 1 290$'
                font_size: 12
                text_size: self.size
                halign: 'left'
                valign: 'middle'
            AnchorLayout:
                anchor_x: 'right'
                TextInput:
                    id: name_input
                    multiline: 'False'
                    width: 60
                    size_hint_x: None
            Button:
                text: '+'
                on_press:
                    app.add_item('Item 1', '290', name_input.text)



            Label:
                text: f'Item 2 250$'
                font_size: 12
                text_size: self.size
                halign: 'left'
                valign: 'middle'

            AnchorLayout:
                anchor_x: 'right'
                TextInput:
                    id: name_input2
                    multiline: 'False'
                    width: 60
                    size_hint_x: None
            Button:
                text: '+'
                on_press:
                    app.add_item('Item 2', '250', name_input2.text)


BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'

    MDToolbar:
        title: 'Store'

    MDBottomNavigation:

        MDBottomNavigationItem:
            name: 'Items'
            text: 'Main'
            icon: 'home'

            MDBoxLayout:
                orientation: 'vertical'
                pos_hint: {'center_y':0.5}
                adaptive_height: True
                spacing: 2

                MDRaisedButton:
                    text: 'Items'
                    pos_hint: {"center_x":.5}
                    width: dp(250) + (self.ids.lbl_txt.texture_size[0] - self.ids.lbl_txt.texture_size[0])
                    on_release: Factory.Bases().open()

        MDBottomNavigationItem:
            name: 'Basket'
            text: 'Basket'
            icon: 'basket'

            ScrollView:
                size: self.size

                GridLayout:
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: self.minimum_height
                    width: self.minimum_width

                    size: root.width * 0.5, root.height * 0.5
                    row_default_height: 35
                    row_force_default: True
                    center: root.width / 1, root.height / 1

                    id: basketItems
                    cols: 4
                    spacing: 4
```

Answer (score 0):

A Convenient way to do this is to put everything that you want to delete at one time into a single widget, so you can just delete that single widget. In your case, that single widget can be a `BoxLayout` that contains your three `Labels` and the `Button`. Then by using another `BoxLayout` instead of a `GridLayout` inside the `ScrollView`, each row can become a single `BoxLayout`. So changing the kv to use a `BoxLayout`:

```
    MDBottomNavigationItem:
        name: 'Basket'
        text: 'Basket'
        icon: 'basket'

        ScrollView:

            BoxLayout:
                orientation: 'vertical'
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height
                center: root.width / 1, root.height / 1
                id: basketItems
                spacing: 4
```

Then, the `add_item()` method can just add a `BoxLayout` to the basket and the `delete_mdRB()` can just delete that `BoxLayout`:

```
def add_item(self, name, price, counter):

    box = MDBoxLayout(adaptive_height=True)
    mdRB = MDRaisedButton(text='delete this')
    mdRB.bind(on_press=partial(self.delete_mdRB, box))  # pass the box to be removed

    box.add_widget(
        MDLabel(text=name, adaptive_height=True, adaptive_width=True)
    )
    box.add_widget(
        MDLabel(text=price, adaptive_height=True, adaptive_width=True, width=60, size_hint_x=None)
    )
    box.add_widget(
        MDLabel(text=counter, adaptive_height=True, adaptive_width=True, width=120, size_hint_x=None)
    )
    box.add_widget(
        mdRB
    )
    self.root.ids.basketItems.add_widget(
        box
    )

def delete_mdRB(self, box, button):
    box.parent.remove_widget(box)
    # for child in [child for child in self.root.ids.basketItems.children]:
    #     self.root.ids.basketItems.remove_widget(child)

    finalPrice.clear()
    print(finalPrice)

    finalItems.clear()
    print(finalItems)

    finalCounter.clear()
    print(finalCounter)
```